# How to properly design a system that provides services based on location

Tags: architecture

This is more of a high-level architecture question. If there is a better site to post these at please let me know.

To greatly simplify - think of Uber Eats, but for services. You could order services of a local plumber, local roofer, but also nationwide service like Comcast internet, or some statewide service. "How to order" doesn't matter, assume all you get from backend is the right phone number, and have to make the call yourself. The question centers around the correct way to set up individual services to make sure they can be easily shown to end users based on location.

Here are a few approaches I thought of so far:

1. Set up a specific address for each service. Show the end user services within X miles of their home address. **Problem** - that doesn't let us handle nationwide or statewide services without setting up individual addresses for each single local office. Seems like a lot of unnecessary precision.
2. Set up separate list of services for each city, for each state, and for the country. Based on end user's address show them the services of their city, for their state, and for the country, together in one list. I guess for each service I'd need the optional State and City fields - if empty the service is nationwide, if city is empty but not state - it's statewide, otherwise it's citywide. **Problem** - "citywide" might not be precise enough for big cities. A plumber in a huge city is not likely to go across the entire city for work. Might need a 4th level of services, with precise address and a distance they are willing to travel.

So far it looks like I'd need a combination of both options, which seems like a mess.
How would you handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, even thought there might be a lot of it, the information you're speaking to is relatively static.

With purely static information we can think in terms of (1) information sources and source formats and (2) data and forms appropriate for fast dynamic queries at load.  Then compile & transform the sources in their formats into an appropriate form for fast queries.  In some sense, this is might be merely denormalizing the data, but perhaps on a grander scale.  Indexing can also be precomputed.

With ~relatively static data, we can think in terms of automating the above.  A good automation process that can both re-crunch the source data into the denormalized and indexed forms appropriate for fast read and query, while also managing the versioning of various data sets, and streamlining their roll out (so, for example, rolling out a new data set should not require shutting down services or adversely affect queries in progress).

Farther along on the spectrum, where the data is less static or frequently changing, the CQRS approach suggests application design that pushes this automation toward continuous operation (at considerable application complexity).

Comment: Thank you for the info. The data should be fairly static. New services will be added over time, but existing ones shouldn't change much from day to day.  

How would you structure the DB side of it though? Do I really have to resort to keeping 4 separate lists? One for nationwide services, one for statewide (with state as a column), one for citywide and one for local (precise location and area covered)? Is there another standardized way of doing this?

Comment: I'm suggesting setting up an approach that automates compiling the various sources in whatever form you find them into the form that makes it easy, fast, and scalable to answer your queries.  I would seek to do that over manually pre-processing the sources, i.e. into 4 levels of geography as separate tables.  I would probably start with an analysis of some of the specific data sources, and the some of the specific queries you want to make, and expand from there.

Comment: @madme A lot of databases have some degree of support for geospatial queries (SQL databases and NoSQL).   It may be worth investigating those and testing them to understand how best to design the schema/structure and how to design the queries.    There's also a whole separate StackExchange for GIS which you might find useful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @BenCottrell, I'll check it out as well.